# How do you change one area of a String?

Tags: java, string

if I have a String that I have multiple uses for how do I edit one section of the string?

---

Such as:

```
String Output="|0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |";
```

How would I change and then read just the first zero?
And then do the same for the rest. To make them as their own variables.

Comment: `string.replaceFirst("0", "Foo");`

Comment: It looks like you may be using `String` when another type, such as `int[]` or `List<Integer>` may be better.

Comment: You really shouldn't try to manipulate data in this form. It's awkward, it's slow, and it's unrobust. If at all possible, use an array or list for your variables.

Comment: This sure seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to accomplish? You can't change a `String` at all; `String` objects are immutable. You can create new `String` objects, extract character values, parse substrings as `int` values, etc. Please provide some context for your question so we can provide appropriate help.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
String splits = s.replace("|", "").split(" ");
System.out.println(splits[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> How would I change and then read just the first zero? And then do the same for the rest. To make them as their own variables.

**I wouldn't.** I'd use an array, or a `List`, or object properties, or separate variables, depending on the use case.

But if you really, really want to, you can read any of those values like this

```
int value = Integer.parseInt(Output.substring((n * 4, 2).trim());
```

...where `n` is the zero-based index of the entry you want to get the value of.

You can *write* any of those values like this:

```
String vstr = String.valueOf(value);
if (vstr.length < 2) {
    vstr += " ";
}
Output = Output.substring(0, ((n - 1) * 4) + 2) + vstr + Output.substring(n * 4);
```

But is it readable? No. Efficient? No. :-)

Compare with, say, an `int[]`:

```
int[] values = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

Reading:

```
int value = values[n];
```

Writing:

```
values[n] = value;
```